# iPhone MDM implmentation on Windows & C# - Export .mobileconfig using command-line

Tags: c#, iphone, certificate, mdm

I have successfully created Configuration Profile using [this](http://pastebin.com/fkZMncyB) C# code and iPhone Configuration Utility. Now, I need to export this Configuration Profile to .mobileconfig file using any command-line utility or C# code. I found that CertUtil can be used to export it but can't make it to work. I gone through https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2382238?start=0&tstart=0 link which looks promising but does not work for me.

Can anyone give the exact steps to export .mobileconfig file using any command-line utility or C# code?